# Go to directive definition VS2015 like WebStorm

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio, angularjs-directive, visual-studio-2015, webstorm

Not sure, If this is the right place to ask this question as its not related to any coding area problem.

My project, developed in `AngularJs` with web api, using `VS2015`, have grown big in code and structure. I have written many modules with directives, controller and services. If I am using `webstorm` I can easily navigate to directive definition from html by pressing `CTRL + Mouse Left Click`.

Is there any way like `plugin` or `addon` which I can add to `Visual studio` and manage to get same functionality?

I tried [this](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/643f7067-3777-4c96-ba1f-d544594d5503) but not much useful.

Comment: [Go To Definition extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4b286b9c-4dd5-416b-b143-e31d36dc622b)

Comment: Only works with .cs files not with html to js files.

Comment: Hmm yeah, makes sense. Visual Studio is not really designed as a web editor.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check out these articles:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vscode/2015/05/21/getting-started-with-angular-and-visual-studio-code/

https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript

I know they're tutorials for VS Code, but the shortcuts might be the same.

Comment: Have checked both articles, But not much helpful!